# PostgreSQL - Not using indexes when querying multiple values along with CTE

Tags: database, postgresql, performance, indexing

I recently altered 'resources' table in my DB so that I can support multiple versions of resources.

'resources' Schema:

[image: 1]

I have one index on 'id' column and another one on 'parent_res_id' column.

The query that I use to often is to get all relatives of the resources:

```
WITH r2(id) AS (
    SELECT r2.parent_res_id
    FROM resources r2
    WHERE r2.id IN ( 2, 3 )
)
SELECT r.id
FROM resources r
WHERE
    (
    r.id IN ( 2, 3 )
    OR
    r.parent_res_id IN ( 2, 3 )
    OR
    r.id IN (SELECT r2.id FROM r2)
    OR
    r.parent_res_id IN (SELECT r2.id FROM r2))
;
```

Though when I EXPLAIN ANALYZE this query, Postgres is doing seq scan instead of using indexes in the main query, and only using it for the CTE when I only pass one parameter in `IN` clause.

Query Plan when only 1 param:

```
Seq Scan on resources r  (cost=8.21..21.25 rows=114 width=4) (actual time=0.077..0.078 rows=0 loops=1)
    Filter: ((id = 240) OR (parent_res_id = 240) OR (hashed SubPlan 2) OR (hashed SubPlan 3))
    Rows Removed by Filter: 153
    Buffers: shared hit=13 dirtied=1
    CTE f2
        ->  Index Scan using resources_pkey on resources r2  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=0 loops=1)
            Index Cond: (id = 240)
            Buffers: shared hit=3 dirtied=1
    SubPlan 2
        ->  CTE Scan on r2 r2_1  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=0 loops=1)
            Buffers: shared hit=3 dirtied=1
    SubPlan 3
        ->  CTE Scan on r2 r2_2  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.122 ms
Execution Time: 0.104 ms
```

Query Plan with two or more params:

```
Seq Scan on resources r  (cost=11.99..25.03 rows=115 width=4) (actual time=0.097..0.119 rows=11 loops=1)
    Filter: ((id = ANY ('{211,270}'::integer[])) OR (parent_res_id = ANY ('{211,270}'::integer[])) OR (hashed SubPlan 2) OR (hashed SubPlan 3))
    Rows Removed by Filter: 142
    Buffers: shared hit=20
    CTE f2
        ->  Seq Scan on resources r2  (cost=0.00..11.90 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=0.024..0.033 rows=1 loops=1)
            Filter: (id = ANY ('{211,270}'::integer[]))
            Rows Removed by Filter: 152
            Buffers: shared hit=10
    SubPlan 2
        ->  CTE Scan on r2 r2_1  (cost=0.00..0.04 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=0.029..0.039 rows=1 loops=1)
            Buffers: shared hit=10
    SubPlan 3
        ->  CTE Scan on r2 r2_2  (cost=0.00..0.04 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=1 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.132 ms
Execution Time: 0.152 ms
```

What is the reason for this and could this be optimized for better performance?

Comment: Your table looks very small, like 154 entries, maybe? That would explain why Postgres doesn't even bother with the index. Have you tried to insert a lot more data and see what's happening?

Comment: There are conditions when a sequential can be *much faster* that an index lookup. This case is one of them. A small table can be read with 1 physical i/o (the slowest possible but necessary action) but an indexr equires a minimum of 2 physical i/os: 1 for the index and 1 for the base table.  The other case is a large table and a non-selective index where a substantial percentage (10%) must be read anyway. This is also a case of premature optimization as in both cases total time < 0.0003 sec. Improve it: nobody will notice - ever. See [here](https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/1044.php)

Comment: Thanks JPMoresmau and Belayer. 
I had less data on local and was trying to optimize production issues, which was not an ideal scenario for this.